# draper - Help understanding delegate with "to" and "prefix"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, draper

Given that I have a class that inherits from `Draper::Decorator`, like this:

```
class PageDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  delegate :title, :name, :region, :keys,
       to: :glass_decorator,
       prefix: :glass

  def full_title
    full_title = []
    full_title << glass_title if glass_title
    full_title.join(" ")
  end
```

There is a decorator called `GlassDecorator` in another file in the same directory.

1. What does the `delegate` line actually mean? Does it mean that when I try to access the `title`, `name`, `region`, `keys` attributes/methods, they will be delegated to the `GlassDecorator` ? What does the `prefix:` part mean?
2. For the `full_title` method, Does the `glass_title` part try to lookup the `title` attribute/method in the `GlassDecorator`? If that is the case, is it made possible only because of the `delegate` line? If so, is it the `:prefix` portion that makes it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)
`:prefix` will add the prefix to the front of the method-name. eg "glass_title" instead of just "title"
`delegate` means that if somebody calls `glass_title` on your `PageDecorator`, it will then go and call `title` on the `GlassDecorator` and hand you the result. ie - it delegates that method to the object named in `:to`

2) yes. You have understood that correctly

Comment: Hmm, am I right to say that if I keep everything in the code the same and omit the `prefix:` portion and I try to access `title`, it will be first be looked up in `PageDecorator`, then if it does not exist, `title` will be looked up in `GlassDecorator`, and if that fails, in the decorated object?

Comment: I don't think so. If you have "delegate" it won't look in your current model. If you have a method called "title" on PageDecorator, it will overload the delegated one.

Comment: You'd have to write one that checked the local value, then tried the delegated one... and name them differently.